# Run an arbitrary number of scripts sequentially using map/reduce and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, promise

I need to run an arbitrary number of scripts. The next one can run only of the previous has loaded and executed. I know RequireJS (and related) would be the correct choice, but I'm trying to learn about promises, so this is my experiment:

```
var files = [
  'first.js',
  'second.js',
  'third.js',
  'fourth.js'
];

var funcs = files.map(function(file) {
  return function() { return $.getScript(file); }
});

var deferred = $.Deferred();

funcs.reduce(function (soFar, f) {
   return soFar.then(f);
}, deferred.resolve(funcs[0]));
```

Can someone elaborate about the pitfalls and alternatives to my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're really looking for is [.pipe](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.pipe/) ( or in 1.8+, I believe .then was changed to mean the same thing )

In short, pipe will allow you to chain promises in the way that you're looking for.  The code might look something like this ( untested ):

```
var files, scriptsLoaded;

files = [ 'first.js', 'second.js', 'third.js', 'fourth.js' ];

while( files.length ) {
    (function() {
        var currentUrl = files.shift();

        scriptsLoaded = scriptsLoaded ?
            scriptsLoaded.pipe(function() {
                return $.getScript( currentUrl );
            }) :
            $.getScript( currentUrl );
    }());
}

$.when( scriptsLoaded ).done(function() {
    // All scripts are now loaded assuming none of them failed
});
```

** Edit **

With that link you provided, I understand what you were trying to accomplish.  Here's a corrected version of your solution with some comments.  It accomplishes the same thing as the other solution, however it's a much more concise version:

```
var files = [ 'first.js', 'second.js', 'third.js', 'fourth.js' ];

// The initial value provided to the reduce function is a promise
// that will resolve when the first file has been loaded.  For each
// of the remaining file names in the array, pipe it through that first
// promise so that the files are loaded in sequence ( chained ).
// The value that is returned from the reduce function is a promise
// that will resolve only when the entire chain is done loading.
var scriptsLoaded = files.slice(1).reduce(function (soFar, file) {
    return soFar.pipe(function() {
        return $.getScript( file );
    });
}, $.getScript( files[0] );
```

Comment: That worked great, thanks! (still trying to understand "pipe" usage). Would you say this approach is better or both are ok?

Comment: The problem with the original approach is that "deferred" is immediately resolved rather than being resolved when all of the requests are completed.  By using .pipe, the deferred that is returned is resolved only when the entire chain succeeds or fails.  My solution can likely be made more concise, but it would still use pipe to chain the tasks together - see http://api.jquery.com/deferred.pipe/#example-2

Comment: Thank ou very much! I've conducted some experiments and with my code, if a force a 404 in "second.js" the rest of the files are not called. My example was adapted from here https://github.com/kriskowal/q#sequences

Comment: Now that you've linked that, I see what you're trying to do.  I'll edit my answer with a corrected version of yours in addition to my solution.